# unable to get ZedGraph PointValueHandler event to fire

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I've created a PointValueHandler, and added the event using:

```
this.zg1.PointValueEvent += new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl.PointValueHandler(this.myPointValueHandler2);
```

However myPointValueHandler2 never gets called.

I have a similar event for MouseDoubleClick, which gets called perfectly.

The only difference I can see is that the MouseDoubleClick event method returns a void, where myPointValueHandler2 returns a string. The form designer by default adds a void method, which I manually changed to a string return.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you set zg1.IsShowPointValues = true ?

Comment: yes - the standard PointValue tooltips are shown, and I can even change the format using PointValueFormat and PointDateFormat, but I can't get my own event to fire.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I right-click on the graph, and turn off "Show Point Values", nothing changes - ie default pointValue tips are still displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isShowCursorValues was set to true. This needs to be false, and then the event is called

Answer (score 0):

Set IsShowPointValues to true, then the event is called.